# How tax import export works in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 added tax rates import & export functionality, but I am not understating this module. Can you please explain in details?

Comment: Please provide the details of what you intend to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are few places, where `import/export` of taxes functionality is available:

1. **Stores->Tax Rules**. Add or edit some tax rule. In the bottom you can see block, which allows you to import/export tax rates.
2. **Stores->Tax Zones and Rates**. See, that above the grid there is a link, which gives you ability to export your tax rates either to csv, or to xml.
3. **System->Import/Export Tax Rates**. It is the page, which provides you the same functionality as in place 1.